# Sending SMS from PC without splitting the message into parts

Tags: windows, android, ubuntu, sms

I know there are a lot of apps that enable sending SMS through PC/Laptop. I've tried a number of them. But my **problem is these apps break my message into parts when the messages exceed 160 characters**. I tried a number of apps but all seem to have the same problem.

Finally, I found [MyPhoneExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client&hl=en) which catered to what I needed. It is just what I needed. I was happy, but not for long. I realized that MyPhoneExplorer does not exist for Linux based systems. By 'does not exist', I mean there is no official release of the app for Linux based systems. There is help provided on how one can get the app working on Linux using [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/). Unfortunately, none of the tutorials helped me.

So lastly, I simply want to know if there exists any app that would enable me to send text messages through my Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) + Windows laptop without breaking my message into parts. **A lightweight app would be a thumbs up since my phone is a bit low on memory**.

**Android version on Phone:** *4.4 KitKat*

**OS on laptop:** *Dual boot system running Windows 7 Ultimate (32-bit) & Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit)*

Comment: When you send texts longer than 160 characters, they are automatically split. Your phone merges them without your knowing on the other end. It's why it's called SMS: **Short** Message Service.

Comment: Have you tried [Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/)? It works on your computer as Chrome extension and synchronizes SMS when the phone is connected, allowing you to seamlessly switch to and fro between phone and computer.

Comment: Yes, I have tried Pushbullet. It is an awesome application but has the same problem. It splits the messages. The only app I've come across that doesn't is MyPhoneExplorer which works on Android + Windows, but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work on Android + Ubuntu.

Comment: As Chop wrote: 160 chars is the upper limit for the length of an SMS. The only alternative to splitting would be cutting then (throw away the rest) – or reverting to MMS, which might mean additional cost. There is absolutely no way to send a single SMS with more than 160 chars, sorry – neither on Android nor iOS nor Windows. This is a technical limit (I could explain the background, but that might go to far and doesn't help you either).